# How to subplot two histograms with one mirror with respect to the other in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, merge, histogram

I want to merge these two histograms up and down into one.

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: You seem to have inverted the x-axis as well.  Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without any examples.

Here some mock up data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xaxis = np.array(([1,2,3,4,5]))
x1 = np.array(([6,7,8,9,10]))
x2 = np.array(([10,9,8,7,6]))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(xaxis, x1) #blue bar
ax.bar(xaxis, -x2) #orange bar
ax.vlines(xaxis, -x2, x1) #alternatively black line, remove this if not needed
```

output:
[image]